# Which Filter should be used for Editor

Tags: editor

For Form Editor xml, should we use
filter="safehtml" 
or
filter="JComponentHelper::filterText"

Pl advise - which is better filter and safe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell from looking at the codebase, both end up filtering the code through `JFilterInput::getInstance()->clean();`, which checks the html is safe.

The main difference seems to be that `JComponentHelper::filterText` has some additional filtering to limit the html to a bespoke whitelist/blacklist.

Both should be secure.  The latter may have more flexibility should you need it.